# about morphisms of affine formal schemes $\mathrm{Spf}(B)\to \mathrm{Spf}(A)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, soft-question, formal-schemes

It is well known that there is a correspondence between homomorphism of rings $A\to B$ and morphism of affine schemes $\mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

**Question:** (1) In analogy, is there anything similar between homomorphism of adic rings and morphisms of affine formal schemes $\mathrm{Spf}(B)\to \mathrm{Spf}(A)$? 
(2)What could be good references for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See EGA I, sec. 10. For the specific question you mention, see paragraph 10.2. There is further issues on the cohomology of formal schemes in EGA III, sect 3.4. Also, the existence theorem is treated in the volume "Fundamental Algebraic Geometry: Grothendieck’s FGA explained", Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 123 (2006), A.M.S.

Comment: Thank you, I founded it in the monograph for FGA (8.1.1.2). By the way there all rings are assumed to be noetherian, I was wondering if the noetherian condition is crucial.

Comment: @Hang The noetherian hypothesis is crucial inasmuch the flatness of completion fails without this hypothesis among other nice properties. There is of course room to develop a theory of non noetherian formal schemes but up to now there are only partial attempts, in my opinion.